# Synaptics Touchpad Will Not Scroll - Refuses to Reset without full Restart

Tags: windows-8.1, scrolling, synaptics-touchpad

I'm on Windows 8.1 using an HP Envy 17t. I haven't had problems until yesterday.

OK. Yes, I found that one thread that said to run this bat:

```
taskkill -f -im syntpenh.exe
cd C:\Program Files\Synaptics\SynTP
start "" "syntpenh.exe"
exit
```

It does not work.

OK, so now that's out of the way. I have not done updates to my computer. It's been months - don't say I need to update drivers or anything like that. They've worked just fine, no other software updated.

OK, so now *that's* out of the way.

Full description: I cannot scroll with the touchpad in most windows. The *one* window I can, is the Task Manager. I have no idea why.

The problem started when I began to play a text-based browser game called Rise of Tyrants. I've played it for years, picked it up again yesterday.

I also run autohotkey, where this script is active:

```
$*Numpad1::
$*Numpad2::
$*Numpad3::
$*Numpad4::
$*Numpad5::
$*Numpad6::
$*Numpad7::
$*Numpad8::
$*Numpad9::
VarB1 := SubStr(A_ThisHotKey,9)
Send !+%VarB1%
return
```

Essentially, this just remaps pressing a numpad to pressing Alt+Shift+number so that I can use that feature of the game more easily.

I can manipulate the game a lot faster, that's cool.

I'm playing in Firefox v43.0.1 with 6 addons. Close other tabs, Dorando keyconfig, QuickDrag, Scriptish, Snap Links Plus, and Stylish. Stylish is not running any styles. Scriptish runs a script that removes tabstop from certain page elements. I do not believe it to be relevant enough to break my touchpad.

OK. So the breaking happens spontaneously. I can go minutes without attempting to scroll, so it is unknown when it breaks.

I have been able to solve it by closing Facebook in Firefox in a separate Firefox profile that was running concurrently. I thought that was interesting. It made me suspect maybe my computer is overloaded and thus bugging out?

Problem is, it has happened again since then. And without facebook open. So I thought, OK, maybe another program like Netflix encouraged the break? Closed that. Closed every program except one Windows Explorer window. Still didn't work to fix it.

So, I have no reliable fixes except a full on restart of my computer. That's annoying.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing it? Too rapid use of the numpad? Too rapid use of artificial Alt and Shift keystrokes causing Synaptics to abandon the scroll in non-Task Manager windows?

The only thing that has changed is my use of the numpad extensively in concurrence with the autohotkey script, and a dedicated firefox profile. None of that suggests to me that my scrollpad should stop working in all windows except the Task Manager. But maybe it makes sense to someone else?

Comment: Quick update: Me doing nothing fixed it. It spontaneously allowed scrolling after I submitted this comment. I had tried moments before my submission to scroll, just for the heck of it, and it was not working.

I made this submission with a firefox-fork browser, in case that has any relevance.

Comment: Did you also attempt to suspend or exit the autohotkey?

Comment: Yep. I killed that script and any other AHK scripts I had running. Doing so didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: **Q2**: Which scrolling mode do you have enabled? Using reserved area on edge of the touchpad or using two fingers anywhere or ...?
**Q3**: While the problem is present, could you evaluate other functionalities of the touchpad, if they work as before? **Q4**: Could you set up the AHK to capture and indicate ScrollUp and ScrollDown to ensure they are really not working? **Q5**: Could you stop using the Firefox for a while and carry your activities in another  browser? Did browser change caused the problem to disappear? If you then return to the Firefox, does the problem reappear shortly?

Comment: **Q6**: does sleeping and waking up the computer resolve the problem? (At least for a few moments, even if it returns shortly.) If not, what about computer hibernation+wakeup? **Q7**: does disabling and re-enabling the touchpad in Device Manager resolve the problem? (The touchpad can be found connected as USB device.)

Comment: @miroxlav Sorry for not seeing these questions 6 months ago. I'll answer them just in case this helps anyone coming across this problem:

**A2**: Two finger scrolling, not the edge.
**A3**: As far as I know everything worked fine, but I only use it for left click, right click, two finger scrolling, and moving the mouse.
**A4**: Not to my knowledge, I've never learned to detect the message that the touchpad's messages (wouldn't be great if I did).
**A5**: I didn't use firefox, but a fork. But it was a problem in all applications except Task Manager, guess because that was with admin rights

Comment: **A6**: Not that I noticed, but I don't recall if I tried, short of a full restart.
**A7**: Nope, that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also on Windows 8.1 laptop with Synaptics touchpad and when I'm using the touchpad more frequently, I'm observing it suddenly gets bugged (although in somewhat different way than you described). The same problem was present on Windows 8.0. It looks there is a bug in my Synaptics driver, appearing after minutes (sometimes after hours) of the intense use of the touchpad.

But first, let's get some more information about the behavior as I [asked](https://superuser.com/questions/1147140/synaptics-touchpad-will-not-scroll-refuses-to-reset-without-full-restart?noredirect=1#comment1649055_1147140). There is still a chance there is something else causing the problem.